# Export runtime value of a variable in NetBeans

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, runtime, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans for Java programming and I want to export the value of a variable into a file, since I can't do it by copy and paste like a big array list. Is there any command to do this at runtime?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to persist the data for future runs of your program? What have you tried?

Comment: actually i have a breakpoint in my program and it took a long time for my program to compute an arraylist and reach this point. i want to export this variable to a file so that i directly import it into an array list if i encounter an exception afterward. this way it doesn't require to wait this long time again to reach that point because i have the value of that array list and i restart the program from this point again.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump heap with tools like `jmap` (part of jdk). To have a snapshot of your application memory.

But I don't think there's a way to "paste" values on NetBeans for the fields/variables. You can go and change them manually. But what if the current array have 4 elements and the one you saved have 9? How will be the object references?